# How save dict in csv in column form where the first line is keys and next lines are vectors?

Tags: python, csv

I have a dict which is in the following form:

```
Sigs_dict['a']=[1,2,3,4,5]
Sigs_dict['b']=[6,7,8,9,0]
Sigs_dict['c']=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

I whould like to have a csv file where the first line is the keys of the dict and the next line the vectors in a column shape.
Like:

```
a    b    c
1    6    1
2    7    2
3    8    3
4    9    4
5    0    5
```

what I have for now is the first line but I don't understand how to write the vectors properly.

```
with open(fileName[0], 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ' ')
    writer.writerow(Sigs_dict.keys())
    #missing something here
```

All vectors have the same length.

Comment: You could use `pandas` library and create a dataframe like your expected output. Then just use `to_csv` method in order to write the object to a csv file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple option using the [`zip` built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) (no `pandas` dependency, eventhough `pandas` allows for less code lines):

```
my_dict = {}
my_dict['a'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
my_dict['b'] = [6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
my_dict['c'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# get keys and values in the same order, in this case, sorted by key
# key_list = sorted(my_dict.keys())
key_list = [k for k, _ in sorted(my_dict.items())]
val_list = [v for _, v in sorted(my_dict.items())]

with open(fileName[0], 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=' ')
    writer.writerow(key_list)
    for row in zip(*val_list):
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Note how I unpack `val_list` using the asterisk (`*`); without that unpacking this won't work as expected.

---

Edited my code to have a fixed ordering to prevent mismatch between column header and content.

Comment: Would recommend `zip(*sorted(Sigs_dict.values()))` to keep the order

Comment: I have an issue with this solution because I get an empty line each time I insert a new row

Comment: `zip(*sorted(Sigs_dict.values()))` would not keep the order.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It will keep the values sorted as per keys as posted by OP in the question

Comment: @ymmx you need to add `newline=""` when opening the file, which python version are u using

Comment: @mad_ ok for `items()` not for `values()`

Comment: Ohh didn't realize it was just `values()`. The idea is to sort by keys to preserve the order.

Comment: Modified my code to explicitly have keys and values in a fixed order; thanks for pointing that out. This way there is more code, but it is more explicit in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

If you are ok with using pandas

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(Sigs_dict).to_csv('your_csv_file_path.csv',index=False,sep=' ')
```

Will produce

```
a b c
1 6 1
2 7 2
3 8 3
4 9 4
5 0 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Even if the input is a dictionary, you cannot use `csv.DictWriter`, which would require 1 key per data *row*, not column.

Just `zip` the dict values (in a fixed order) to "transpose" and create rows that `csv` module can write properly.

Also, sort your dict keys so the order of columns is the same everytime:

```
import csv,sys

title = sorted(Sigs_dict)
cw = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
cw.writerow(title)  # write header
cw.writerows(zip(*(Sigs_dict[k] for k in title)))
```

result:

```
a,b,c
1,6,1
2,7,2
3,8,3
4,9,4
5,0,5
```

to write to a file, don't forget `newline=""` for python 3, and `"wb"` for python 2 to avoid the infamous extra newline issue on windows:

```
with open(fileName[0], 'w', newline = "") as f:  # or just ,'wb') for python 2
   cw = csv.writer(f)
```